# Determine when user leaves WinJS app

Tags: windows-runtime, cordova, winjs

I'm building some very basic analytics for in-house WinJS apps. Take this to mean that a 3rd-party analytics solution would both overkill and/or unworkable and/or against the 3rd-party providers terms of use as they generally disallow capturing personally identifiable information about the user, and in this case that is a business requirement.

The thing I'm trying to do is determine how much time is spent in multiple apps, and in areas within certain areas of the app. For this I obviously need to know when they enter and leave.

All the documentation I've found says to use the `WinJS.Application.oncheckpoint` event or the `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onsuspending` event, which really seem to be two access points into the same basic concept. The problem is this doesn't accurately reflect when the user leaves the app! Suspend seems to happen only after the user has switched to another app, plus about 10 seconds ...... if the system feels like it.

If the user simply hits the Windows key to go out to the Start Screen and just sits there, the app continues to run indefinitely (calls to setInterval are able to affect state) even though the app cannot be seen!

I understand this is a bit of an edge case, but is there any more reliable way to tell when the user can't see the app, for lack of a better definition?

**Notes:**

- I did look at the Cordova 2.7 code for Windows 8 and they are using the checkpoint event to drive the Cordova pause event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App Visibility section on [Application lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx/css) seem to address this. This means registering for `msvisibilitychange' event, to know when user moved away and moved back to your app.

```
default.js:
document.addEventListener('msvisibilitychange', function ()
{
    console.log('visibility changed');
    console.log(document.visibilityState); // 'hidden' or 'visible'
});
```

In addition, [suspending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.webui.webuiapplication.suspending.aspx/css), [resuming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.webui.webuiapplication.resuming.aspx) and activated events also needs to be handled.

```
default.js:
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onsuspending = function ()
{
    console.log('suspending');
}

Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onresuming= function ()
{
    console.log('resuming');
}
```

Needless to say, that nuance of ordering, and/or event being absent cases needs to be handled. For example - if the user moves away and comes back quickly, visibilitychange event will be received. whereas if user does not come back suspending event may come after some time. if the app is not terminated, it may be followed by resuming event. otherwise, activated event.

regards spending time on specific pages, page `ready` and `unload` method should work. `unload()` will not get called if the app is suspended or terminated.

Comment: Use `visibilitychange` in a Windows 10 app (Edge webview).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/visibilitychange

Use the visibility change event to recognize when the user can no longer see the app.

Comment: I thought it was odd that a Mozilla link was referenced to answer a WinJS question, but it does work! The crucial thing from this link to note is that once the event happens you need to check document.visibilityState to see if it's 'visible' or 'hidden'.